# HTTP host base routing

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

Which software can help to do like that:

> - request to http://host1.mycomp.com on port 80 will be NAT to PC1 on port 80.
> - request to http://host2.mycomp.com on port 80 will be NAT to PC2 on port 80.

We have only 1 IP. host1 and host2.mycomp.com point to the same IP.
Some one say that nginx will help, someone say that url rewriter will help.
Please show me how to do it.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I am using nginx now but not satisfied yet.